# Adding multiple fragments in same FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my container xml file as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_products"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/slideshow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_categories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want to add more than two fragments in FrameLayout(id: home_categories). But when I try to add multiple fragments in the that FrameLayout, second fragment replaces the first one and even second fragment is not displayed fully (contains ListView).

TheCode:

```
public class TheHome extends Fragment{
    private Category[] categories;
    private SubcategoryList[] subcategoryList;
    private boolean added = false;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.i("Attched","Yes");
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Activity","CreatedOfTheHome");
        final FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager() ;
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.search_products, new SearchProductsFragment(), "SEARCH_PRODUCTS");
        transaction.add(R.id.slideshow, new SlideShowPageFragment(),"SLIDE_SHOW");
        Log.i("TheHome","BeforeHandler");
        Handler holderForCategories = new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.i("TheHome","ReceviedMessage");
                for(int j = 0 ; j < categories.length ; j ++) // a loop to add mutliple fragments
                {
                  Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                  transaction.add(R.id.home_categories, new CategoriesAndSubcategories(context, categories[j], subcategoryList[j].subcategories),"CATEGORY"+j);

                }transaction.commit();
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };
        getCatsAndSubcats(holderForCategories);
    }
    public void getCatsAndSubcats(final Handler handler)
    {
        Log.i("TheHome","GetCatsAndSubcats");
        RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity())
                .getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, Links.URL_CATLIST, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject json) {
                        Log.i("TheHome","ResponseReceived");
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("categories");
                            JSONObject preamble = array.getJSONObject(0); //outermost object
                            int totalCategories = Integer.parseInt(preamble.getString("total"));
                            categories = new Category[totalCategories]; //total number of categories
                            subcategoryList = new SubcategoryList[totalCategories];
                            for(int i = 0 ; i < totalCategories ; i ++)
                            {
                                categories[i] = new Category() ;
                                JSONObject object = preamble.getJSONObject("cat"+(i+1));
                                categories[i].label = object.getString("category_name");
                                categories[i].background = object.getString("background_color");
                                JSONObject subcategory = object.getJSONObject("subcategories");
                                int totalSubcategories = Integer.parseInt(subcategory.getString("total"));
                                subcategoryList[i] = new SubcategoryList() ;
                                subcategoryList[i].subcategories = new Subcategory[totalSubcategories];
                                for(int j = 0 ; j < totalSubcategories ; j ++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject subcat = subcategory.getJSONObject("sc"+(j+1));
                                    subcategoryList[i].subcategories[j] = subcategoryList[i].new Subcategory() ;
                                    subcategoryList[i].subcategories[j].label = subcat.getString("label");
                                }
                            }
                            Log.i("TheHome","GoingToSendMessage");
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                        Log.i("VolleyErrorFromCats",arg0.toString());
                    }
                });
        Log.i("TheHome","RequestSent");
        queue.add(request);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("OnCreateView","OfTheHome");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_home, container, false) ;
        return view;

    }
  class SubcategoryList
   {
       class Subcategory
       {
           String label ;
       }
       Subcategory[] subcategories;
   }
  class Category
   {
       String label;
       String background;
   }
}
```

Even when I am dynamically creating a FrameLayout for each fragment I am adding, first fragment is not displayed anyway. Second fragment is displayed (the list view) which contains 11 children in it, but it shows just one.

Here,

```
    Handler holderForCategories = new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.i("TheHome","ReceviedMessage");
                for(int j = 0 ; j < categories.length ; j ++)
                {
                  FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
                  FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                  frameLayout.setId(j);
                  linearLayout.addView(frameLayout);
                  Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                  transaction.add(frameLayout.getId(), new CategoriesAndSubcategories(context, categories[j], subcategoryList[j].subcategories),"CATEGORY"+j);

                }transaction.commit();
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to replace

```
 transaction.add(R.id.search_products, new SearchProductsFragment(), "SEARCH_PRODUCTS");
 transaction.add(R.id.slideshow, new SlideShowPageFragment(),"SLIDE_SHOW");
```

with

```
 transaction.replace(R.id.search_products, new SearchProductsFragment());
 transaction.replace(R.id.slideshow, new SlideShowPageFragment());
```

Let me know if it still not worked.

Comment: Above two fragments are added successfully even with their tags not removed. I think the problem is with the loop, where I am adding multiple fragments (through loop, may be about five of them).

Comment: Yes, transaction.replace seems to work. But why transaction.add does not work?

Comment: Please see add (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)) and replace (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int, android.app.Fragment)